# What's the best optimization you've ever used?

Tags: optimization

One of biggest optimizations I've used is regard to this question:

[import from text file to SQL Server Database, is ADO.NET too slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152414/import-from-text-file-to-sql-server-database-is-ado-net-too-slow)

with the initialized version, insert each row per query use ADO.NET, I was able to insert about 100 rows/second. When I switched to batch insert, it rose to 1000 rows/second, and then, BulkCopy, I can get, about 7000 rows/second. All in same machine. 70 times better and even smaller, more-readable code.

So, what's the best optimization you've ever used to improve your code? Optimization means better tactic/strategy, not premature optimization :)

Comment: BulkCopy rocks, but you also have the hassle of generating your own primary key values

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545844/biggest-performance-improvement-youve-had-with-the-smallest-change

Answer (score 4):

Matrix multiplication by dividing it down to sub matrices small enough to fit inside the processor's cache.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a few optimizations, and the pattern has always been to **use a profiler**, which gives you the bottlenecks, which **tells you where** to start working.

So, for instance I has a form updating live data. The screen was too slow. Profiler said > 10000 calls per minute to drawing function. So, I changed the strategy to simply save the data, and call draw() an acceptable amount. Result: Form isn't stuck, data looks like it's coming in.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Dictionary`/`Hashtable` to look values up by key instead of using a `foreach` loop *(especially for very long lists)*.

And a similar optimization: indexes on databases.

Comment: And `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE` whenever possible!

Answer (score 0):

My brother claims the world record on this. By realigning some bit fields in a *large* Ada program so as not to cross word boundaries he sped up a routine by a factor of over 350,000.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, C++: replacing an CString-based "simple but slow"  string parser with an alternate implementation using a pair of characterpointers as a "string segment".

Came down from 10 minutes to <10 seconds.